# How can I use ILMerge with Windows Phone 7 assemblies?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ilmerge

I've got this working for SL4, but I need an equivalent for my WP7 project:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ilmerge.exe" 
/lib:MyProj.Silverlight\bin\Release /internalize /ndebug 
/targetplatform:v4,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50917.0" 
/out:Download\MyProj.Silverlight.dll MyProj.Silverlight.dll Newtonsoft.Json.Silverlight.dll
```

What's the equivalent `/targetplatform` value for WP7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get ILMerge working with WP7, quick blog post about it [here](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-ilmerge-for-windows-phone-7.html).

I believe from the example above your 'targetplatform' is wrong, it should be:

*/targetplatform:v4,"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ILMerge has been updated for WP7. You could try a silverlight 3 assembly and see if it runs.